# Return a user along with a paged collection of followers

Tags: indexing, ravendb

I'm still learning so maybe my model is currently wrong, but this is what I have so far:

```
Account
{
 string Id,
 string ArtistName,
 List<FollowerAccount> Followers
}

FollowerAccount
{
 AccountId,
 DateBeganFollowing
}
```

So my Account document contains a list of denormalized references to a list of all the accounts that are following them.

I now want to return a list of accounts from 'accounts/1' Followers list, but page them, I know I can do this as 2 queries but I was hoping I could nail this down 2 1 query.

Here is an index I have being playing around with, however I can't get it to work.

```
public class TestIndex : AbstractMultiMapIndexCreationTask<TestIndex.ReduceResult>
    {
        public class ReduceResult
        {
            public string AccountId { get; set; }
            public DateTimeOffset? DateBecameFollower { get; set; }
            public string ParentAccountId { get; set; }
            public string ArtistName { get; set; }
        }

        public TestIndex()
        {
            AddMap<Account>(followers => from follower in followers
                                         from sub in follower.FollowersAccounts
                              select new
                              {
                                  ParentAccountId = follower.Id,
                                  AccountId = sub.AccountId,
                                  DateBecameFollower = sub.DataBecameFollower,
                                  ArtistName = (string)null
                              });

            AddMap<Account>(accounts => from account in accounts
                                        select new
                                        {
                                            ParentAccountId = (string)null,
                                            AccountId = account.Id,
                                            DateBecameFollower = DateTimeOffset.MinValue,
                                            ArtistName = account.ArtistName,
                                        });

            Reduce = results => from result in results
                                group result by result.AccountId
                                    into g
                                    select new
                                    {
                                        ParentAccountId = g.Select(x => x.ParentAccountId).Where(x => x != null).First(),
                                        AccountId = g.Key,
                                        DateBecameFollower = g.Select(x => x.DateBecameFollower).Where(x => x != DateTimeOffset.MinValue).First(),
                                        ArtistName = g.Select(x => x.ArtistName).Where(x => x != null).First()
                                    };
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

RavenDB can't page within the items of a single document, because it treats a doc as an aggregate. So you **can** page complete documents (using Skip/Take), but not the Followers within a single Account document.

So you'll have to resort to 2 database calls, one to get the Account and 1 to query the Followers how are following that account.

However if you use the Lazy request feature of RavenDB you can save on network round trips. See [here](http://ayende.com/blog/63491/ravendb-lazy-requests) and [here](http://ayende.com/blog/63489/ravendb-multi-get-support) for more info.

```
var lazyUser = session.Advanced.Lazily.Load<User>("users/ayende");
var lazyPosts = session.Query<Posts>().Take(30).Lazily();
```

Another thing to bear in mind, how many followers do you expect a single account to have? If it's a large amount you might run into perf issue storing documents that large in RavenDB. The overhead for deserializing very large documents can become an issue.

Comment: After some thought about it, I did actually change my mind and move Followers into a separate document, now I can perform paging very easily and it should scale pretty well too.